# Can you interrupt the initial sync of geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, dag

I have ran the `geth -rpc` and it started syncing. Any idea on how long that should take? And if I interrupt it, will it start again or pick up where it was stopped? Also will the DAG stay always synced by itself or is there some management necessary once I begin mining?

Comment: That will probably take a few hours depending on your internet connection and the hardware you're using. Once synced it should remain sync by itself as long the process is still running. For fast sync I usually prefer parity to geth

Comment: The DAG will take care of itself, don't worry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not specify which version of geth you are using, it is difficult to tell whether it has started in --fast mode or not. If it is a recent version (I think after 1.6.0 or later) then it must be started in --fast mode then it has to complete the syncing process before stopped and it will take less time (from 15 minute to a weekend) depending on your hardware of at least quad core processor, 4gb+ ram, ssd and fast and stable net connection.

But if it is an old version then it must be started in --full mode then it can be stopped any time, it will start from where it left. But, it will take weeks to completely sync regardless of your consumer grade hardware and network connection.

Please refer to issues (I and other user encountered) #14608, #14626, #14647 and #14653 at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.

Comment: I am using the latest stable release, 1.6.6. I have i5 6500 quadcore, 8 gigs of ram and ssd, my connection is around 350. Is the --fast mode the default mode or do I have to run it with it? What's the difference between the fast and normal mode? I plan to mine on my regular PC overnight so geth won't be continually running. Will the syncing take a considerable amount of time every day or is it a one-time load and then it will work just in smaller batches?

Comment: In geth 1.6.6 --fast mode is the default. You cannot stop it before complete sync, when It is changed to full sync mode. In full sync mode your node is going to download every block and check every transaction itself if it is valid or not. Due to various attacks on network there are millions of bogus transaction to check which makes it slow to sync. Hence it takes fast hardware and stable network connection to completely sync. In fast mode it just download blocks and state entries. My take (as Kevin in comments) is not to use geth in fast mode. It is unstable for any less then required system.